# Fix java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect

Tags: java, maven, jackson

Getting following exception while running the program.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAutoDetect
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.VisibilityChecker$Std.<clinit>(VisibilityChecker.java:170)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<clinit>(ObjectMapper.java:261)
    at neustar.mngr.EMRService.getEMRConfig(EMRService.java:40)
    at neustar.mngr.EMRService.getEMR(EMRService.java:22)
    at neustar.helper.EmrLaunchMain.main(EmrLaunchMain.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 5 more
```

The pom entry is given as below.

```
    <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.327</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.515</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The exception is thrown while creating object of Mapper class:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

I am not getting any compilation error. At runtime the exception is coming. Need guidance to fix the issue.
Tried changing the versions of jackson, but it did not help

Comment: Through an IDE? Verify the jars are imported. 2.1.1 should be fine. However, **you should not be mixing AWS SDK versions** as this can do some crazy things.

Comment: I need to launch emr cluster from java project, that's why I am using dependency of aws sdk. I tried printing jackson version being fetched at runtime, its the same as defined in pom.xml . Used "ObjectMapper.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()" to get jackson version at runtime

Comment: Made an uber jar instead of normal jar. It worked

Comment: Using the AWS SDK is fine, but you have BOM 1.11. **327** and SDK 1.11. **515**. These should match up and be both 327 or 515.

Answer (score 0):

JsonAutoDetect should be in jackson-annotations

Check under

```
C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.9.6
```

Can you try to mvn clean
Remove folder: C:\Users\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml
Try newer versions?

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: jackson-annotations is present under .m2 folder. I tried with the latest jar too,  the problem is still there.